# Using Statement removed when I save the project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, enterprise-library

I am new to C# and Enterprise Library and I ran into some weird behavior in the IDE that I was able to resolve, but I thought that it was strange enough that I wanted to get the reaction of other developers and perhaps benefit others.

I wanted to start out by using the Data Access blocks. Using VS2010 and NuGet, NuGet downloaded the data Access DLLS and set the references. However, every time I trued to type the following:

using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;

and then save the project, the line simply disappeared and then I would get a compile error suggesting that I was missing a reference when I tried to enter the following statement:

Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

It didn't help when I tried to bypass the "using" statement by fully qualifying the object.

Finally, I resolved the issue by compiling using the full 4.0 Framework instead of the Client Framework.

My Visual Studio Environment is a bit screwed up, but so far the issue seems isolated to SSIS and SSRS. Is this behavior that others have experienced or is it my computer? It sure seems like unusual behavior to me.

Comment: "My Visual Studio Environment is a bit screwed up" - ???

Comment: The only time I've seen using directives automatically removed is when I ask ReSharper to remove unused ones.

Comment: Try it! If you got NuGet, it takes a second to reproduce the steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not standard VS behaviour. Do you have the VS Power Commands installed? That has an option to remove unused usings on save.

On the Tools menu choose Options and scroll the left window, looking for PowerCommands. If it's there click that entry and then ensure Remove and sort usings on save is unchecked.

If you don't have that plugin installed it will be another plugin doing this.

Comment: I Microsoft's Power Commands of VS2010 disabled and DevExpress' VSCommand 2010 install and that cannot be disabled. I don't see the option you mentioned for either utility, but your answer seems very likely, so I'll take your word for it.